# How to render Django context data (JSON) within external JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, json, django, content-security-policy

**The question I have is**:

How do I get template-ed JSON data to be usable by `.js` file to see and use JSON data from my Django context?

**The problem I am trying to solve is**:

I am working on adding a CSP (Content Security Policy) to my Django website. The catch is that I have some inline JavaScript when templating JSON variables. This wouldn't be a problem, but the [templating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/) is inside the JavaScript section of the `.html` file. Thus, in order to abide by a strict CSP, I need to move the entire JavaScript portion out of the `.html` file and into a `.js` file. The code I need to move looks like this:

```
<script>

let data = [
    {
    "key" : "Last 10 Days",
    "values" : {{ last_ten_days }},
    },
    {
    "key" : "Daily Score",
    "bar": true,
    "values" : {{ daily_scores }},
    }
].map(function(series) {
            series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
            return series;
});
</script>
```

I am passing the values via a Django TemplateView to the context so I can render the data to plot, using NVD3.js, on my webpage. It looks something like this:

```
class TheScores(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'the_scores.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ...
        context['last_ten_days'] = last_ten_days
        context['daily_scores'] = daily_scores
        return context
```

So when move this section of JavaScript out of my HTML template the variable templating of the JSON data for last_ten_days and daily_scores no longer works.

I do not know how to get the JavaScript to see the data without leaving it inline, which would violate the strictness required for the CSP to be of any worth (seems like an all or none thing). So the resultant move creates an external JS file that is the same as above, call it `scores.js`:

**Problem Here:** `scores.js` has no idea how to load `last_ten_days` or `daily_scores` as JSON:

```
let data = [
    {
    "key" : "Last 10 Days",
    "values" : {{ last_ten_days }},
    },
    {
    "key" : "Daily Score",
    "bar": true,
    "values" : {{ daily_scores }},
    }
].map(function(series) {
            series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
            return series;
});
```

Then, when I replace the inline section of JavaScript with `<script src="{% static "js/scores.js" %}" ></script>` the JavaScript does not read the `{{` `}}` as Django variable templating (rightly so). And so the question is, how can I use JSON data via a Django template within JavaScript while implementing strict CSP? Thanks.

Comment: I think it should be `"{{ last_ten_days }}"` in quotes. Similarly with other variable.

Comment: Are you saying the syntax is incorrect? Or that double quotes will get the data to render in JS? If the former, I can assure you the data works without double quotes. If the later, I am keen to know why/how that would work. Thanks!

Comment: I assure you double quotes is necessary ;)

Comment: Thanks. But that is not my question and it is not causing a problem.

Comment: One way would be to treat your `js/scores.js` file as a regular view/template and render it the same way. You would need to create a separate view similar to `TheScores` with the difference that it will output different content type as response. In that case, you will comply with your CSP policy and the file will be dynamically generated instead of loading it from `static` folder.